# How to get tfs extension to on-premise server , for example test manager extension

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfs-2015, microsoft-test-manager

[image: VSTS account]

Couldn't find a way to get the TFS extension to on-premise TFS server, it always finding the VSTS account only. we are not using VSTS. 
Also tried https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/get-tfs-extensions 
from step 3 its different.

all the time it market place find vsts account. its of no use.  Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Test Manger extension could be installed for VSTS and TFS 2017 and upper version.

But for TFS 2015, it doesn't need to installed it separately. In TFS 2015 and TFS 2013, to get the test manager features, you should [change the **Access Level** of your uses to **Advanced**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/connect/change-access-levels#change-the-default-access-level).

1. Login in to the Access level page, usually the path is `http://servename:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses`
2. Add the account under **Advanced** tab. 
   [image]

**Note:** You could also set the Advanced access level to **default**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.